# How can I trim the last two characters of each key in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, substring, associative-array

This is my array (input):

```
$value = array("jan01" => "01", "feb02" => "02", "mar03" => "03", "apr04" => "04");
```

I am using this code to get the array keys:

```
implode(" ", array_map("ucwords", array_keys($value)));
```

Now my problem is I want to get all keys by triming the last two characters of each key.

How can I change/modify my code, so that it trim's the last two characters of each key?

**EDIT:**

I also want to skip first 3 keys, means I don't want the first 3 keys to be trimmed.

Comment: put your code. array structure and what is expected.how we can say what you have to do by seeing this one line. thanks.

Comment: Can you post your array structure along with the expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

Just take the `substr()` from your key and then use `ucwords()` on it.

```
implode(" ",array_map(function($v){
    return ucwords(substr($v, 0, -2));
},array_keys($value)));
```

**EDIT:**

AS from your updated question you don't want to take the substr from the first 3 elements. So just use a counter  variable, e.g.

```
$counter = 1;
echo implode(" ", array_map(function($v)use(&$counter){
    if($counter++ > 3)
        return ucwords(substr($v, 0, -2));
    return ucwords($v);
},array_keys($value)));
```

Comment: one more thing missing part of question, can i skip first 3 keys to trim?

Comment: sorry i have not mentioned in question

Comment: @ImranQamer you need it to check if it is one of the first 3 elements or not

Comment: got that point as you used use(&$counter) too, so it should be ok now, let me check it

Comment: @ImranQamer You're welcome :) (If you provide an example with input, current output and expected output you will get your answer even faster next time, which also makes the question very clear)

Answer (score 1):

Here's something for undetermined array depth.

```
$arr = your array;
$trimmed_values = array();

array_walk_recursive($arr, function($key, $value) use (&$trimmed_values)
{
    $trimmed_values[] = substr($key, 0, -2);
});
```

This won't work if you're not using PHP 5.3+ as lower versions don't have anonymous functions.